# antd dont import all icons

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using only the loading property of Button component.
Internally the button component requires 0.5mb of icons.
Is there is any way to use only loading icon and not the huge icons import?

Thanks.

Comment: Switched to antd-mobile, the button there does not import icons by default

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried for `Icon` components,
 but you can check out [babel-plugin-import](https://github.com/ant-design/babel-plugin-import), which optimizes import statements.

I was able to [make it work](https://www.slightedgecoder.com/2018/09/16/making-ant-design-css-optimization-to-work-on-codesandbox/) with CSS & other AntD components.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is correct, the answer is no. In the meanwhile, you can try another way. download the specific icon as an SVG format form the icon and create your own icon bundle for using [icon moon](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select) and use it. So you can reduce the size.

Bonus point: Always try to import a specific component like below instead downloading whole antd component.

```
import Button from 'antd/lib/button';
```